# flatten list of lists in (key, List[List]) PCollection, retaining the key

Tags: apache-beam

I have a PCollection of (key, value) pairs where the value is itself a list

```
{'apple': ['1','2'],
 'watermelon': ['4','5']
 'apple': ['9','10']
 }
```

I would like to obtain another collection with the same key, but where the list is a `GroupByKey` on the original collection, but where the resulting value is a flattened.

```
{'apple': ['1','2','9','10'],
 'watermelon': ['4','5']
 }
```

instead of

```
{'apple': [['1','2], ['9','10']],
 'watermelon': [['4','5']]
 }
```

I have tried a few things but it's not obvious to me how to go about it.

I guess one can always write a `ParDo` function that flattens the list on a per-element basis but it feels there must be an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logical operation you are looking for is "combine per key" where the combiner is list concatenation (known as `+` in Python).

Depending on the characteristics of your data, you may wish to implement this operation using a new `CombineFn` that mutates a list as its accumulator. This is nearly equivalent to performing a `GroupByKey` and then flattening the lists afterwards in a `ParDo`.

The difference in execution is that a `Combine` operation can be performed before shuffling your data, because the Beam runner knows that it is an associative and commutative operation. In this case, it will not reduce the amount of shuffled data so it is not so important.

Comment: right. So I should think of it as a "reduce" operation with list concatenation as the operator, where the reducer is called a combiner here. I think that makes sense, will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this

```py
import apache_beam as beam


class Combiner(beam.CombineFn):

    def create_accumulator(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return {}
    
    def add_input(self, acc, element):
        key = element[0]
        value = element[1]
        if key in acc:
            value.extend(acc[key])
        acc[key]=value
        return acc
    
    def merge_accumulators(self, accumulators):
        return accumulators

    def extract_output(self, accumulator):
        return accumulator

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
    pipe =(
        p
          |'create'>> beam.Create(
                
                [
                ('apple', ['1','2']),
                ('watermelon', ['4','5']),
                ('apple', ['9','10']),
                ('watermelon', ['49','50'])
                ]
                
 )
          |'combiner'>>beam.CombineGlobally(Combiner())
          |'print'>>beam.Map(print)
             
    )

#o/p - [{'apple': ['9', '10', '1', '2'], 'watermelon': ['49', '50', '4', '5']}]
```